# Is "differs from sth to sth by sth" grammatical?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, verbs

I want to say that :

> The effective population size differs **from** British population **to** Americans from Africans ancestry **by** a change in the bottleneck.

I am comparing between British population size and the Americans of African Ancestry population size, they are both different only in the bottleneck, which  refers for the migration history of both pop.

To simplify my question neglecting all these academic terms, can I say that:

> The skin color differs **from** European **to** Africans only **by** a change in melanin?

Can I use the verb "differ" in this way?

Can I say "X differs from A to B by C"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL RORI! Unfortunately, your question sounds like proofreading, and that is off-topic here.

Comment: We might need more context. What do you exactly mean to say? Please explain the meaning of your sentence by [edit]ing it.

Comment: in other words : I want to say that Americans and British are different in the effective size by a change in the bottleneck

Comment: @Cardinal [sentence-construction] is a pretty poor tag. I'd love to improve the existing set of tags on the question, and suggestions are welcome, but not *that* tag.

Comment: @TIPS I think OP are talking about his problem about constructing a natural sentence. However, I agree that he also asked about a verb and its usage. Thus, I think word-choice can also be a tag.

Comment: @Cardinal no, word-choice is for something else. (I don't remember, maybe the tag wiki is clear enough on that?) The problem is not with solely the name of the tags, but how well they serve their purpose. The usage tags and [sentence-construction] are examples of traitors.

Comment: OP, I'm still trying to understand your sentence. Are you aiming to say that the median age in America is different than that of Britain?

Comment: No the population size is different

Comment: Then would you please explain what population has to do with "[bottleneck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_bottleneck)"? It's related but doesn't fit your sentence.

Comment: the thing that both population are different in is the bottleneck that I mentioned in the sentence.. it is the only difference between the two populations i mentioned

Comment: But you've just said that the sizes of the two populations are different. Is that the same thing as "bottleneck"?

Comment: Yeah they are different because of this bottleneck I mean it is what makes that difference

Comment: What exactly does "bottleneck" mean in this context? How is it the cause of different population sizes? And what populations are being compared? All Britons and all Americans? All Britons and Americans of African ancestry? Britons of African ancestry and Americans of African ancestry? -- All your answers should be included **in the question** by editing it (there's an *edit* link immediately beneath the question) so that answerers will understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Okey , I have edited the question

Comment: @RORI bottleneck:  a dramatic reduction in the size of a population (as of a species) that results in a decrease in genetic variation. Do you mean this?

Comment: @RORI what is the migration histiry of both.populations? Can you explain it or provide a link? If we don't understand what you exactly mean, we cannot help you to communicate what is in your mind through words. So help us know more. We don't know the whole story the way you know, as we are not in your mind. Give more info. What us the relation between these population that you are comparing. I feel they are different and yhere is no or very little similarity between them.

Comment: So lets guess. You mean British pepole who migrated to America and African Americans. The only diffference between them is **bottleneck**. Now which one is decreased in genetic variation, British emigrants or African Americans? How this difference in bottleneck is related to **they differ in change in melanin**? I ask this question because you are in a way reducing the information you provided for us, which you call **academic terms**, to **The skin color differs from European to Africans only by a change in melanin.**. I don't see any direct relevance between them.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I say "X differs from A to B by C"?

No.

If we are speaking of X, some quality or quantity possessed by both A and B in different amounts, we say that

> X differs **between** (or **in**) A and B . . .
>   Mean skin color differs between/in American and British populations of African ancestry . . .

*From* is used when we compare A with B:

> A differs **from** B **in** X . . . 
>   The American population of African ancestry differs from that of Britain in mean skin color . . .

In either of these, *by* is used to characterize the scale of the difference, not a cause:

> {X differs between A and B / A differs from B in X} **by** Y
>   Mean skin color differs between American and British populations **by** 5.2 points.
>   The American population differs from the British population in mean skin color **by** 5.2 points.

If you want to ascribe the difference in X to a difference in some other variable, Z, you have many options: you can mix-and-match various prepositionals (e.g.,*because of*, *due to*, *by virtue of*) with various descriptions of the differential factor (e.g. *the difference in their respective Zs*, *their different Zs*, *differing Zs*, *their having different Zs*).

> The American population of African descent differs in mean skin color from that of Great Britain **by** 5.2 points by virtue of their having significantly different proportions of melanin.